# XenServer guest crashes upon connection to console

Tags: xenserver, windows-10, xencenter

Background: XenServer 6.5 with Windows 10 guest, Windows XP guest, and 2 Linux guests.

Has been running fine for 2+ months.

Yesterday, when I opened XenCenter and clicked the Windows 10 client's Console tab, the client apparently froze.  (Or the graphics driver crashed, I can't tell.)  LogMeIn and Splashtop both lose their connections.

The Linux and Windows XP guests don't exhibit this behavior.

I had to do a Force Reboot on this guest to get it back.  Still can't click its Console without losing all remote connections (LogMeIn and Splashtop) and requiring a Force Reboot.

Any ideas how to troubleshoot and/or fix this?
(I posted on the Citrix forum but Tobias hasn't had a chance to reply yet)

Thanks!

Comment: UPDATE: This issue is still occurring.  I notice that the CPU utilization goes to 100% and stays there upon attempting to access the Console.  I have modified the XenCenter console options in various ways but to no avail.  It would be great if someone could shed some light on this!

Answer (score 1):

Please configure your xenserver console to be in native mode. You can change the behavior before clicking the VM.

Remove that option in red and ne sure the one over is check

[image]

By default it use RDP, and if an install in the windows corrupted the monitor driver you can have this issue as your logmein seem affected too.

In your xenserver you could in the cli run xe task-list and validate if multiple connection to the console exist too. You can cancel all by using xe task-cancel uuid=idFoundByLaterCommand

Comment: Thanks @yagmoth555 for the info. How do I configure xenserver console into native mode?  and why would this "stop working" after being fine for multiple months?

Comment: @RyanGriggs Hi, check the updated answer, I put a printscreen. For the why please check in the VM if something changed, as if the rdp client got a problem it might be related to something new in the VM. An xencenter console update might not hurt, but be sure to find the cause before

Comment: it's now 9 months later and I'm still having this problem.  If I connect to the guest from the Console tab, it completely freezes - can't see the screen from console or remote access (Splashtop).  Have to Force Shutdown.  Please help!